# Changing notation within a subsection LaTeX

Tags: symbols

I was just wondering if there was a quick fix for this problem. Essentially I have a subsection of my thesis written up with the variable `$\xi$` appearing everywhere. To be consistent with the rest of the thesis I should really change this, `$\eta$` would be a better option. Is there a way for me to 'tell' LaTeX that within subsection X.X.X read `$\xi$` as `$\eta$`? It would save me a lot of time and hassle not having to change every occurrence of `$\xi$`!

Thanks.

Comment: sed 's%\\xi%\\eta%g'..

Comment: @nbubis - Wouldn't that change all \xi to \eta - not just in the subsection of interest?

Answer (score 9):

You could put

```
\let\oldxi\xi\let\xi\eta
```

at the start of the section and

```
\let\xi\oldxi
```

at the end.

Although I wouldn't do that, I'd edit the source. Any editor would change all `\xi` to `\eta` in a section in less time than it took you to post the question....

Comment: The subsection is perhaps 30 pages long and includes extensive asymptotic expansions. It was MUCH quicker to post the question. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Juggler the math might be complicated but `sed -i -e 's/\\xi\b/\\eta/g' section5.tex` would fix it wouldn't it? I say I'd do that as the above `\let...` isn't entirely safe if for example you have `$\xi$` in a subsubsection heading, it will typeset as eta in the heading but be written as `\xi` and typeset as xi to the table of contents, similar considerations if you have math in `\index`. Fixing such moving text is possible but quite a bit harder and more fragile, compared to simply editing the file.